# Is there a good method for making sophisticated (and terse) code into more verbose code?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

For example, this is really nice code, but my first instinct is to make it more verbose so it is easier for a beginner to read:

```
stateSet = Tuples[{0, 1}, 6] // Rest;
gatherTestFunc = Function[lst, Sort[RotateLeft[lst, # - 1] & /@ Flatten[Position[lst, 1]]]];    
stateClsSet = Sort /@ Gather[stateSet, gatherTestFunc[#1] == gatherTestFunc[#2] &];
stateClsSetHomogeneous = ArrayPad[#, {{0, 6 - Length@#}, {0, 0}}] & /@ stateClsSet;
```

It would be nice to have a program or perhaps just a systematic method for replacing # and / and @ .  I've always found Slot to be confusing!

Comment: `# &` can be turned into `Function[x, ...]` although it's important to be careful with scoping in nested cases. They can also always be turned into small pattern-based functions which are basically by definition easier to read because they have a name specifying their intent. `/@` is just `Map` which can be turned into an explicit `Table` call if that will help people read. OTOH my guess is the biggest issue is going to be stuff like `Sort[RotateLeft[...] ... ` where multiple operations are done at once. That can be easily decomposed into more imperative stuff using `Module` and local vars.

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly what you want, but it leverages a built-in utility:

```
ClearAll[printCode];
SetAttributes[printCode, HoldAllComplete];
printCode[code_] :=
  Block[{myCode},
   myCode[] := code;
   GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[myCode];
   ];

printCode[
 stateSet = Tuples[{0, 1}, 6] // Rest;
 gatherTestFunc = 
  Function[lst, 
   Sort[RotateLeft[lst, # - 1] & /@ Flatten[Position[lst, 1]]]];
 stateClsSet = 
  Sort /@ Gather[stateSet, gatherTestFunc[#1] == gatherTestFunc[#2] &];
 stateClsSetHomogeneous = 
  ArrayPad[#, {{0, 6 - Length@#}, {0, 0}}] & /@ stateClsSet;
 ];
```

[image]

It uses `@` for one-argument function calls.  I think that's easier to read, but there is a unstated seeming preference for code that looks more like C (or maybe Java or whatever).  That only makes sense if it is to be assumed that a beginner is somehow familiar with some other programming language.

---

I thought there might be feedback about how close the above was, since the goal is a little vague.  With a lot more work, we can get the minimal benefit of getting rid of `Slot` (which I've always liked, pure functions appealing to math persons).  A minimal attempt was made at avoiding name clashes by appending a "$" at the end of function and parameter names.  It would be nice to break down certain compositions (as @b3m2a1 suggested) or tooltips that trace the computation...but dream on.

[image]

```
ClearAll[printCode2];
SetAttributes[printCode2, HoldAll];
printCode2[code2_] :=
  Module[{nFn = 0, code, fnrules},
   Block[{myCode},
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{GeneralUtilities`Debugging`PackagePrivate`makeDefinitionNotebook},
     
     GeneralUtilities`Debugging`PackagePrivate`makeDefinitionNotebook[
        c_] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := Block[{$in = True},
       GeneralUtilities`Debugging`PackagePrivate`makeDefinitionNotebook[
        c /. {RowBox[{TemplateBox[{"Global`myCode", 
               StyleBox["myCode", GrayLevel[0]]}, "DefinitionSymbol"],
              " ", "@", " ", k_}] :> 
           TemplateBox[{"Global`F" <> k, 
             StyleBox["F" <> k <> "$", GrayLevel[0]]}, 
            "DefinitionSymbol"],
          RowBox[{TemplateBox[{"Global`myCode", 
               StyleBox["myCode", GrayLevel[0]]}, "DefinitionSymbol"],
              "[", k_, "]"}] :> 
           TemplateBox[{"Global`F" <> k, 
             StyleBox["F" <> k <> "$", GrayLevel[0]]}, 
            "DefinitionSymbol"]}
        ]
       ];
     
     code = Hold[code2];
     fnrules = Cases[
       code,
       f : Verbatim[Function][body_] :> 
        With[{nargs = 
           Max@Cases[Hold[body], Slot[k_] :> k, Infinity]},
         With[{n = ++nFn},
          Hold[body] /. 
            Slot[k_] :> 
             With[{s = Symbol["X" <> ToString[k] <> "$"]}, 
              s /; True] /. Hold[expr_] :> (
             Evaluate[
               myCode[n] @@ Append[
                 Table[Pattern[
                   Evaluate@Symbol["X" <> ToString[k] <> "$"], 
                   Blank[]], {k, nargs}],
                 ___]
               ] := expr
             );
          f -> myCode[n]]
         ],
       Infinity];
     
     code /. fnrules /. Hold[e_] :> (myCode[] := e);
     GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[myCode];
     ]
    ]
   ];
```